# NAT-Traversal implementation for P2P connection

Tags: c++, linux, networking, nat

I need to implement a simple P2P application behind NATs. It should send data over a reliable and secure connection (Encrypted data over TCP). From the theoretical background I know there are several NAT-Traversal techniques (for example Session Traversal Utilities for NAT) described in several RFCs (5389, 5769, and 5780).

Though in practice I can't find needed tools/libraries to implement such a system (preferably in C++ programming language). What I already found by googling around blindly: [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment),
[TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TURN),
[libnice](http://nice.freedesktop.org/wiki/),
[libjingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html) and [STUNTMAN](http://www.stunprotocol.org/)

Below image describes what it should look like. I have a VPS with valid IP address, a PC behind a NAT and a sensor behind another NAT. They have private IPs. I want my sensor to connect to server, find monitor and send connection request to it. After connection establishment, relay server should not be used to direct traffic of data. I want my sensor and monitor to use this path to communicate:

```
Sensor <--> AP0 <--> R3 <--> {THE INTERNET} <--> R2 <--> Monitor
```

Currently all data is transmitted through VPS:

```
Sensor <--> AP0 <--> R3 <--> {THE INTERNET} R1 <--> 
VPS <--> R1 <--> {THE INTERNET} <--> R2 <--> Monitor
```

[image: Network]

‌

Comment: I know that I shouldn't even ask, but port forwarding or UPnP support is out of question?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly No I just forgot to mention. I'm completely confused. Can't turn my head around and find a start point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if you can [port forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding), then this is more of a infrastructure question than programming. You Just need to configure the routers to direct traffic from the public IP / Port to the Private IP / Port, e.g.:

```
R2: Port 500 - TCP -> Laptop-PT - Port 500
R3: Ports 16000/16500 - TCP/UDP -> PDA-PT - Port 16000/16500
```

If you want to get fancy and your routers support [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), just resort to a library that implements the [IGD protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) (e.g., [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr/)), in order to make your application control the port mapping. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27237/Easy-Port-Forwarding-and-Managing-Router-with-UPnP) provides a good starting point as well as some sample code (although I would really recommend a robust library).

Comment: Do I need to access router configuration?

Comment: Yes. Either manually (as @chris pointed out, configuring the router through it's administration interface) or, if the router supports UPnP (and it is enabled) through a UPnP library. Take a look at the article in my answer, I think that it will make things clear.

Comment: I read that article. Now I can think about port forwarding using UPnP.  So, how are routers in real world? Should I worry about lack of UPnP support in all routers of data path ?

Comment: Most routers now days are UPnP capable, but you will find counter examples, as well as Network Administrators that disable UPnP for security reasons. You should talk with the network administrators.

Comment: Thanks. Going go try it, I think I should study a lot of RFCs and codes. Will come back after tests :P

Answer (score 2):

Because you ultimately want the relay server to be completely removed and want the monitor and endpoint to communicate directly - you really are trying to solve the problem of direct communication between two servers behind NATs.

And so there are two problems to solve:

1) Allowing the sensor to obtain the public IP address of the monitoring system.

2) Allowing the SYN packets for your TCP connection to be relayed through the NAT on Router-PT R2 to your monitor.

The first problem the relay can help with:  You can use TURN to relay a message through the server to communicate the public IP address of the monitor to the sensor.

The second problem however, I'm not aware of any generalized solution for because it really comes down to the configuration on the router.  The router needs to know which of the many systems behind the NAT to forward the SYN to.  It can't forward it to all of them: they would all respond.

Most NAT-enabled routers have configuration settings that allow you to configure which host you want incoming packets to be routed to.  Look at either making the Laptop monitoring system a DMZ, or directing traffic for a particular TCP port to your desired system.  However, each router will treat this configuration differently; there is no standardization of that configuration that I'm aware of.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, but because TCP connections are point to point, and you don't want that data to be forwarded through the relay server, it cannot help in the connection establishment (except, as I said, in obtaining the public IP address of the monitor)

Comment: Put another way; the relay can help in communicating the parameters for setting up a TCP connection, but it cannot help in any data transmissions for that actual TCP connection; including the hardest part - the first packet that is sent for a TCP connection: the SYN packet.