# Private P2P Chat (NAT Traversal question)

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, nat

I am new to networking and have a question regarding p2p and NAT traversing.

I have two PCs with known different static public IPs (IPv4). The first PC (#1) belongs to me, the second one (#2) belongs to my friend.

I want to write a simple P2P chat app which would allow me to exchange messages between these two PCs. The public IPs are known to me and my friend. Also, our local IPs are also known ( #1 is connected to a local private network where all devices share the same public IP). I would like to avoid port forwarding thus I am looking for a way to use some NAT traversal techniques. I would appreciate it if you can share thoughts on this matter.

P.S.

I am familiar with Python, C/C++, Java, C#
P.S.S.
The answer here
[NAT-Traversal implementation for P2P connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341177/nat-traversal-implementation-for-p2p-connection)
assumes port forwarding.

Comment: Look up "UPnP".

Comment: @user253751 I need P2P.

Comment: ... look up "UPnP"

Answer (score 0):

Here are two NAT traversal methods we always use: upnp & nat-pmp, you can search them in github and use them to realise P2P communication between two different internal IP. But one thing you need to notice is that these techs need the support of router.

Comment: What about STUN/TURN servers?

Comment: STUN/TURN need a relay, but upnp/nat-pmp don't need. What's more, STUN/TURN can do trivial thing to Symmetric nat.